# SQL multi join and performing Count query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, filemaker

So i have a database on FileMaker with the following model below :

```
Table A (parent_idA)-------Table B(fk_parent_idA)
                                 (fk_parent_idC)-----------Table C(parent_idC)
```

I want to perform a query that will show me field_A from records of Table A and a count of related records from Table C, with the condition that a field called 'status' in table C has value of 'complete'.

Any records records from table A that have no related records from C that are complete should not show in the query.

[image: Table relationships]

Please help, thanks!

Comment: provide the table structure or schema rather

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please put some efforts in framing a question with **relevant and minimal sample data** showcasing your requirements, and **corresponding expected output**. Please read this link: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: I have updated with the sample of the schema

Answer (score 0):

Although your description is not clear, I believe `inner join` should do it.

```
select table_a.field_a, count(table_c.id) 
from table_a inner join table_b on
table_a.id = table_b.table_a_id 
inner join table_c 
on table_c.id = table_b.table_c_id 
where table_c.status = "COMPLETE" 
group by table_a.field_a;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need `table_a` for this query:

```
select b.parent_idA, count(*) 
from table_b b inner join
     table_c 
     on c.parent_idC = b.fk_parent_idC 
where c.status = 'COMPLETE' 
group by b.parent_idA;
```

Answer (score 0):

Reimagine your graph with PLANS on the left, each plan has a consortium and status. No need to change the actual relationships, just move the tables around to make it easier to visualise. Then the SQL you want, I believe, is:

```
ExecuteSQL ( "

SELECT c.name, COUNT(s.id)
FROM CONSORTIUM c
JOIN PLANS p ON p.consortium_id = c.id
JOIN STATUSES s ON p.status_id = s.id
WHERE s.status = 'complete'
GROUP BY c.name
" ; "" ; "" )
```

I've provided a link to a demo file which should help!

[FM SQL Demo](https://www.layout59.com/examples/SQL_Stack.fmp12)